# how documentum method timeout performed?

Tags: timeout, documentum, documentum6.5, executiontimeout

I have documentum dm_method

```
create dm_method object
set object_name = 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
set method_verb = 'xxx.yyy.Foo',
set method_type = 'java',
set launch_async = false,
set use_method_server = true,
set run_as_server = true,
set timeout_min = 60,
set timeout_max = 600,
set timeout_default = 500
```

It invoked via dm_job with period 600 second.
But my method can work more than 600 second (depend on size of input data, produced by users)

Whats happens whan max_timeout exceeded on dm_method implemented in java?

DFC job manager send Thread.interrupt()?
DFC waits for finishing job and only log warning? 
I didn't find detailed description in Documentum documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See Discussion on https://forums.opentext.com/forums/discussion/153860/how-documentum-method-timeout-performed

> Actually, it's possible that the Java method will continue running in
>   the JMS after timeout. However, the Content Server will already have
>   closed the OutputStream where the method can write the response. So
>   you will most likely see errors in the log, and also in the job object
>   if the method was called by a job. Depending on what the method does,
>   it might actually be able to complete whatever it needs to do.
>
> However, you should try to set the default timeout to a value that
>   will give your job enough time to complete cleanly.

Comment: Now it is on https://forums.opentext.com/forums/discussion/153860/how-documentum-method-timeout-performed after the transfer of Documentum from EMC into OpenText.